# How to show a list of processes that are launched upon a login?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, services

There are some processes that are launched upon a login, how to get a list of these processes?
I want to prevent some processes from being launched automatically.

Comment: For the prevention part of your question: [How can I control (start/stop) applications and services that start up after reboot?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/66498/8546)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

launchd and the Login Items pane of Accounts preferences are the two places that normally start a process when you log in.

If you don't see the item in System Preferences -> Accounts -> specific account ->  Login Items then you will have to look into launchd.

Basically the LaunchAgents and LaunchDaemons folders in ~/Library

Lastly, if they are not there, then it's a system level launchd task that you might want to use launchctl to show or look in /Library instead of the user level library.

Most people just have to manage the preference pane. Here is a snap of mine showing the *Activity Monitor* selected and ready to be deleted if I press the <kbd>–</kbd> button.
[image]

Comment: System Preferences -> Accounts -> specific account -> Login works but how to disable a process?

Comment: If you are the user then just delete from this preferences pane - if for another user then can't if they can run it at another time - if they can run they can choose to run on login

Comment: I'll add a picture to show the command for deleting an item if it's found in the Login Items preference pane.

Comment: Plus: the lesser used, but still valid, *Startup Items* directories. Please see the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to investigate `launchctl(1)` because there are a couple of contexts you will need to account for .

The easiest way is to look at the plist files in:

/System/Library/LaunchDaemons # System Context. Faceless. root lives here.
/System/Library/LaunchAgents  # Loginwindow, or Aqua, where you live, context
/Library/LaunchDaemons
/Library/LaunchAgents
~/Library/LaunchDaemons
~/Library/LaunchAgents

In the file you will see the *default* state of that daemon or agent.  That is a sure way to tell if it is running at boot.

I mention the above degrading, foolish and time consuming method, because it is good to see all the stuff running.  They claim the resources used are low for a loaded yet dormant daemon, but since 95%+ of them are set to RunOnDemand... to me that's running.

Don't actually do that for real though. There is a much easier way.

### Remember

When you log in and open Terminal/iTerm, you are in **Aqua** context.

**Loginwindow** context is when you see the login window, unsurprisingly, and a ton of things run off that.

If you

```
sudo zsh  # why not be comfortable?
```

or some other method to get a root shell, the root user will be in **System** context, which is the context that all the daemons in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons run in.

I mention all this because the tool provided:

```
man 1 launchctl
```

has a verb,

```
launchctl list
```

which you might think from the man page, lists all the running services.  You might feel it plausible, to switch to root, to get a higher level view of what runs when you login.

Sadly, each user sees his own context.

```
launchctl managername
```

will tell you what it is.

For root, its System.
From my nifty hidden admin user, it's **Background**, which is the same thing you get by typing

```
>console
```

into the username box for login

You can use the verb

```
launchctl bslist
```

Which tells you what services are active, for *you*.  It's different for _spotlight, for the hidden admin, for root, for macports etc.

### Answer

The command to see the whole tree, is

sudo launchctl bstree [-j]

whatever you see when you run that after booting is what is running system wide.  For your identity:

```
launchctl bslist
```